# Linux server -- verifying bootability of initramfs image

Tags: linux, boot, initramfs

how does one verify the bootability of initramfs image without actually rebooting the system  -- the reason why we need this is - suppose if one takes the system for a short window and suddenly finds that the initramfs image is corrupt and has to do recovery

one idea I got is to transfer this image to a Virtual machine and boot it off of that ..?

can we extract the image and compare its contents to a golden image , so to speak  . image which we think is not damaged.

thanks,
~Sai

Comment: How are you creating corrupt initramfs images?

Comment: there could be many reasons why the initramfs images gets corrupt - incorrect shutdown , disk issues  and what not -- point is -  we need to make sure the image is bootable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qemu` to test your `initramfs` files.

```
qemu-kvm -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64 \
  -initrd /boot/initramfs-3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64.img \
  -hda foo
```

The system will obviously fail to boot since the `hda` option points to a dummy file. It should be enough to prove that an `initramfs` is bootable, though. Provide a valid `qcow` image if in doubt.